# Какое значение возвращает sqlite3 в переменную python при обращении к несуществующей записи БД?

Tags: python, sqlite3, защита

При отсутствии записи в БД должно выводить 'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' не найден в базе!' но вместо этого ошибка:   File "C:\Users\Дмитрий\PycharmProjects\DataBases\main.py", line 19, in db_table_val
return film.fetchone()[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def end_message(message):
        if message.text == "ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ":
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ДЛЯ ПРОСМОТРА ФИЛЬМА ВВЕДИТЕ КОД В ФОРМАТЕ<<123>>')
        else:
            val1 = db_table_val(message.text)
            pic1 = db_table_pic(message.text)
            rkb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
            rkb.add('ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ')
            if val1 is not None:
                if pic1 is not None:
                    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=pic1, caption='Фильм № ' + message.text + ' называется:             ' + val1, reply_markup=rkb)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' называется:             ' + val1+ '(Обложка отсутствует)', reply_markup=rkb)
            else:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' не найден в базе!', reply_markup=rkb)
```

Comment: Как очевидно из текста ошибки, `film.fetchone()` вернул None. Ну дальше вместо того, чтобы пытаться из None достать элемент, обработайте None так, как вам требуется

Answer (score -1):

Sqlite3 если не находит ничего, то просто выдает ошибку NoneType, тоесть возвращает объект, у которого нет типа. Вам следует использовать `try except`:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def end_message(message):
            try:
                if message.text == "ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ":
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ДЛЯ ПРОСМОТРА ФИЛЬМА ВВЕДИТЕ КОД В ФОРМАТЕ<<123>>')
                else:
                    val1 = db_table_val(message.text)
                    pic1 = db_table_pic(message.text)
                    rkb = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
                    rkb.add('ИСКАТЬ ФИЛЬМЫ')
                    if val1 is not None:
                        if pic1 is not None:
                            bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=pic1, caption='Фильм № ' + message.text + ' называется:             ' + val1, reply_markup=rkb)
                        else:
                            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' называется:             ' + val1+ '(Обложка отсутствует)', reply_markup=rkb)
                except:
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Фильм № ' + message.text + ' не найден в базе!', reply_markup=rkb)
```

Вы также возможно забыли установить соединение с базой данных, после чего закрыть это соединение.

Comment: Во-первых, абсолютно у любого объекта есть тип, даже у объекта None есть тип NoneType. Во-вторых, NoneType не является ошибкой. В третьих, вместо маленькой проверки на None городить перехват абсолютно всех исключений в огромном куске кода — крайне вредный подход

Comment: NoneType - один из видов, ошибки ErrorType. А так да, я не заметил, что человек не проверял на None, извиняюсь.

Comment: В Python не существует ничего с названием ErrorType, вы какие-то глупости из головы выдумываете

Comment: TypeError* https://pythonz.net/references/named/typeerror/

Comment: TypeError существует, но к None не имеет отношения. У автора ошибка TypeError возникла из-за того, что он пытается получить элемент из объекта, который не умеет отдавать элементы (то, что таким объектом оказался именно None, в целом просто случайное совпадение)

Comment: В любом случае, условие с вариантом None поможет, проблема закрыта.